# How can I filter related collection with "and" condition (Hibernate Criteria API)

Tags: hibernate, criteria

Object `Site` has collection of objects `Tag`. Object `Tag` has property `Title`. How can I select all sites with tags 'A' and 'B' using Hibernate Criteria API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that the native SQL you are trying to generate looks something like the following:

```
select *
from Site st
where st.id in (
    select tg.site_id
    from Tag tg
    where tg.title in ('A', 'B')
)
```

I think that the following Criteria example will give you your desired result (You may need to edit the property names).

```
DetachedCriteria d = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Tag.class, "tg");
d.setProjection(Projections.projectionList().add(Projections.property("tg.siteId")));
d.add(Restrictions.in("tg.title", new String[]{"A", "B"}));

Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Site.class, "st");
criteria.add(Subqueries.propertyIn("st.id", d));
```